# PYOMO Constraints - setting constraints over indexed variables

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, pyomo, non-linear

I have been trying to get into python optimization, and I have found that pyomo is probably the way to go; I had some experience with GUROBI as a student, but of course that is no longer possible, so I have to look into the open source options.

I basically want to perform an non-linear mixed integer problem in which I will minimized a certain ratio. The problem itself is setting up a power purchase agreement (PPA) in a renewable energy scenario. Depending on the electricity generated, you will have to either buy or sell electricity acording to the PPA.

The only starting data is the generation; the PPA is the main decision variable, but I will need others. "buy", "sell", "b1" and "b2" are unknown without the PPA value. These are the equations:

[Equations that rule the problem (by hand).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DH0k.jpg)

Using pyomo, I was trying to set up the problem as:

```
# Dataframe with my Generation information: 

January = Data['Full_Data'][(Data['Full_Data']['Month'] == 1) & (Data['Full_Data']['Year'] == 2011)]
                                                                  
Gen = January['Producible (MWh)']
Time = len(Generacion)
M=100
# Model variables and definition: 

m = ConcreteModel()
m.IDX = range(time)
m.PPA = Var(initialize = 2.0, bounds =(1,7))
m.compra = Var(m.IDX, bounds = (0, None))
m.venta = Var(m.IDX, bounds = (0, None))
m.b1 = Var(m.IDX, within = Binary)
m.b2 = Var(m.IDX, within = Binary)
```

And then, the constraint; only the first one, as I was already getting errors:

```
m.b1_rule = Constraint( 
    expr = (((Gen[i] - PPA)/M for i in m.IDX)  <= m.b1[i])
 )
```

which gives me the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5d5f5584ebca> in <module>
      1 m.b1_rule = Constraint( 
----> 2     expr = (((Generacion[i] - PPA)/M for i in m.IDX)  <= m.b1[i])
      3  )

pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.pyx in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.NumericValue.__ge__()

pyomo\core\expr\logical_expr.pyx in pyomo.core.expr.logical_expr._generate_relational_expression()

AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'
```

I honestly have no idea what this means. I feel like this should be a simple problem,  but I am strugling with the syntax. I basically have to apply a constraint to each individual data from "Generation", there is no sum involved; all constraints are 1-to-1 contraints set so that the physical energy requirements make sense.

How do I set up the constraints like this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple things to fix.  First, the error you are getting is because you have "extra parenthesis" around an expression that `python` is trying to convert to a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator).  So, step 1 is to remove the outer parenthesis, but that will not solve your issue.

You said you want to generate this constraint "for each" value of your index.  Any time you want to generate copies of a constraint "for each" you will need to either do that by making a constraint list and adding to it with some kind of loop, or use a function-rule combination.  There are examples of each in the pyomo documentation and plenty on this site (I have posted a ton if you look at some of my posts.)  I would suggest the function-rule combo and you should end up with something like:

```
def my_constr(m, i):
    return m.Gen[i] - m.PPA <= m.b1[i] * M
m.C1 = Constraint(m.IDX, rule=my_constr)
```

Comment: Hi AirSquid, Thanks for answering! I was actually trying something like that as well, but I was getting confused. When you write "def my_constr(m, i)" and then you pass "Constraint(m.IDX, rule = my_constr)", I somehow feel like what the function requires as input and what you give it do not mach; how is the logic of that syntax? I have seen it but I did not really understand.

Comment: Okey I have tried your function and now it raises the following error:                      ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for constraint C1 with index 0:
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'
ERROR: Constructing component 'C1' from data=None failed: TypeError:
    unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Have you read the dox on constraint making?  https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Constraints.html

Comment: You are making a class function that is being called internally by the guts of pyomo when you run the program, so you are not seeing the actual "call".  The structure above is correct.  There is something wrong with your data or formulation, which can't be discerned from what you have posted.  Perhaps it is `Gen[i]` which you have posted as both `Gen[i]` and `Generacion[i]` but have neither defined in your model variables ?

Comment: No, I had a document but I will give that a read. What you mention about the Gen is true, I checked yesterday and added but I must be doing something wrong. I am squeezing time between work related stuff to do it; I will try to update as soon as possible and comment (could be next week). Thanks for your time to answer so far  @AirSquid